# Select with subquery select not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I keep getting that error on this code. I am not using EXISTS.Please Help.

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

SQL:

```
    If ISDATE(@grpsearch) = 1
        SELECT     grp.GroupID,
                   vlanlist.InternetType, 
                   grp.GroupName, cast(grp.StartDateTime as date) as StartDate, 
                   convert(varchar,cast(grp.StartDateTime as time),100) as starttime,
                           (select case when datepart(hh,convert(datetime,grp.StartDateTime)) > 12 then datepart(hh,convert(datetime,grp.StartDateTime))-12
                            else case when datepart(hh,convert(datetime,grp.StartDateTime)) = 0 then '12' else datepart(hh,convert(datetime,grp.StartDateTime)) end end as starthour,
                            datepart(mi,convert(datetime,grp.StartDateTime)) as startmin, case when datepart(hh,convert(datetime,grp.StartDateTime)) >= 12 then 'PM' else 'AM' end as startperiod),
                    cast(grp.enddatetime as date) as EndDate, 
                    convert(varchar,cast(grp.EndDateTime as time),100) as EndTime, 

                    grp.UserInitials, 
                    grp.UserComments,
                    roomlist.RoomName, 
                    jacklist.JackNumber


FROM        a_Cisco.dbo.grp_internet as grp left outer join
            dbo.jacklist as jacklist ON grp.intJack = jacklist.intJack left outer join
            dbo.roomlist as roomlist ON grp.intRoom = roomlist.intROom left outer join
            dbo.vlanlist as vlanlist ON grp.VlanID =  vlanlist.VlanID

WHERE  (convert(varchar,cast(grp.StartDateTime as date),100)  = @grpsearch)
```

Comment: Please post the complete query, otherwise it's impossible to say what might be the issue. If I had to guess you're using a IN or NOT IN clause in the WHERE statement which has a subquery that returns more than one column.

Comment: sorry and no I am not using and IN did not think it was needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this part of the query:

```
      (select case when datepart(hh,convert(datetime,grp.StartDateTime)) > 12
                   then datepart(hh,convert(datetime,grp.StartDateTime))-12
                   else case when datepart(hh,convert(datetime,grp.StartDateTime)) = 0 
                             then '12' else datepart(hh,convert(datetime,grp.StartDateTime))
                        end
       end as starthour,
```

First, you don't need the `select` at all.  Second, you are missing the closing parentheses (`)`).  I would suggest:

```
      (case when datepart(hh,convert(datetime,grp.StartDateTime)) > 12
            then datepart(hh,convert(datetime,grp.StartDateTime))-12
            else (case when datepart(hh,convert(datetime,grp.StartDateTime)) = 0 
                       then '12'
                       else datepart(hh,convert(datetime,grp.StartDateTime))
                  end)
       end) as starthour,
```

Comment: Thanks fixed the code to your suggestion all seems well one little mistake that is the ugly part of coding

Comment: @Henry . . . I am very careful about indenting my code and using parentheses to help prevent these types of mistakes.